# I wish I met/ I had met/ I could meet her

Tags: subjunctives

I'm having some trouble with this sentence, it would be kind enough if someone could help me...
Let, I never met my mother-in-law coz she had died long before we got married, in this case what should I say...

> a. I wish I met her.
> b. I wish I had met her.
> c. I wish I could meet her.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence b is correct. You wish (now) that you had met her (in the past). You need "had" because "wish" takes a past tense (eg "I wish I was rich"), and so the hypothetical meeting needs to be doubly in the past. This means your sentence a is wrong. As already answered, sentence c usually assumes it is still possible to meet her.

You could also use "I wish I could have met her."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the answer is C. I wish I could meet her.
A. is not looking appropriate in this context.
B. is something like, you went somewhere and you didn't meet her and now you are wishing it missed meeting her.
So, I think C is perfectly matching to your context.

Answer (score -1):

if you answered c. I wish I could meet her. that's mean she is still alive and you wished the ability of meeting her